# How do I use a "wrapper function" to call a recursive function without parameters n amount of times?

Tags: c++, function, recursion, wrapper

So for a homework assignment we have to do the partial fraction definition of the golden ratio( n +(1/(n + 1/(.....) but we need to do it recursively. OK, not a problem I can do that.... but we need to call this recursive function 1000 times and cannot use parameter functions. The professor said to limit it to a finite number of calls we can use a wrapper function, but I have never heard of this term in class and do not know where to start on the wrapper function? Could someone help me out?

Please if you can tell me how to do it without sending me the solution to the partial fraction part itself, i'm doing poorly in this class and want to learn it on my own. I just need help with wrapper function. Thankyou!

Comment: So like a header file? or a function in the program itself? And how would I do that for a count? Sorry if it seems like i'm pressing @Joachim Pileborg

Answer (score 1):

A "wrapper function" is a function which *wraps* another function. It's essentially another function which calls the actual function.

As a simple and *unrelated* example, consider you want to get the maximum value of `x` and `10`. You could call [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) directly like `value = std::max(x, 10)`, but you don't want to pass the value `10` all the time, so you make a *wrapper* function:

```
int max10(int x)
{
     return std::max(x, 10);
}
```

The function `max10` is a wrapper function.

---

A possible solution for your problem is to not make the actual function recursive, but the wrapper function. The wrapper function will take one argument, `n`, which is the number of recursions it should make. If `n` is larger than zero then you call the actual function, and then make a recursive call to the wrapper function with the argument `n - 1`.